# What a load of...?

Tags: american-english

A: You're such a bad loser.

B: What a load of crap/bullshit. I'm a great loser.

Any Americans here who could tell me what is more natural to use here - crap or bullshit?

Comment: Former British citizen here: "What a load of bollocks"

Comment: Older British citizen here: "What a load of tosh!"

Comment: For a less sweary version, British = rubbish / American = garbage.

Comment: My father used to say "That's a load of my arse".

Answer (score 0):

Either one is fine in terms of grammar and meaning, and they mean the same thing.

"shit" (and therefore "bullshit") is considered slightly ruder and more offensive than "crap", but neither are very offensive in normal circumstances.